# How to show placeholder content in Xamarin WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is there a way to have a **placeholder shown in a WebView** while a webpage is being loaded?

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which show web content via a WebView. While the web content is being loaded, I would like to show a placeholder - e.g. a blurred version of a standard page - to make the transition look smoother. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this? (Assuming the answer is different on iOS and Android, so answers on any of the two platform are welcome!)

I have a custom webview renderer (Xamarin.iOS), and I think this is the place to to something, but I don't know what the *something* actually is. Help is appreciated.

```cs
class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer 
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null) 
        {
            //...
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null) 
        {
            //...
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: A place holder usually is a View out of the WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need a custom renderer to display a placeholder. The `WebView` exposes a `Navigating` and a `Navigated` event that fire when the view starts and finishes navigating (see the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.WebView/)).

You can subscribe them from XAML

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <WebView AbsolueLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Navigating="WebView_OnNavigating" Navigated="WebView_OnNavigated" />
        <ContentView x:Name="Placeholder" AbsolueLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <!-- Whatever you'd like to display as a placeholder -->
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and implement showing and hiding the placeholder in your code behind

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    // constructor elided

    public void WebView_OnNavigating(object seender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Placeholder.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public void WebView_OnNavigated(object seender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Placeholder.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

When you are navigating to a website, `WebView_OnNavigating` is called and the placeholder is shown. When the `WebView` has finished loading, `WebView_OnNavigated` is called and the playceholder is hidden.

*Remarks*:

- Personally I would not implement it that way, but use a behavior to translate the events to commands and bind them to a viewmodel, change a `IsBusyLoading` property from there and bind that to the visibility of the placeholder
- AFAIK `OnNavigated` is not called unless the page is loaded completely. I have seen websites that loaded indefinetly, due to some bugs, which would cause the placeholder to be shown forever. In that case an `AnctivityIndicator` that is shown above or on top of the `WebView` could be a better UX, since the user would actually see the parts of the page that have already been loaded.